# Proving $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}=0.90900900090... $ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, rationality-testing

> Now I am proving the number $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}=0.90900900090... $$ is irrational.

Here I use a similar method to the proof of *[e is irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational)* by Joseph Fourier. My attempt is as follows.

**My Attempt:** Assume that it is a rational number. Then there exists $ p,q\in \mathbb{Z} $ (with $ q\neq 0 $) such that $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}=\frac{p}{q} .$$

Choose $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ 10^{n}>q+1 $ and $ n=\frac{k_{0}(k_{0}+1)}{2} $ for some $ k_{0}\in \mathbb{N} $.

Put $$ x=q10^{n}\left( \frac{p}{q}-\sum_{k=1}^{k_{0}}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}\right). $$

Then $$x=10^{n}p-q10^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{k_{0}}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}$$ and hence $x$ is an integer.

Clearly $$x=q10^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}>0.$$

Now I need to show $x<1$. But I can't seem to obtain that $x<1$. My attempt for this part is as follows.

$$x=q10^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}<q10^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{n+k}}<q\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{k}}=\frac{q}{10^{k_{0}}}<...$$

Could anyone please give me some help to show $x<1$ ?(if my choice for $x$ is correct. if it is wrong then, what is the suitable choice for $x$ ?)

Any hints/ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Simplest is to use the fact that a number is rational iff it has a terminating or ultimately periodic decimal expansion.

Comment: I know it is true and easy. But here i need to apply Joseph's method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose $n=k_0(k_0+1)/2$ with $10^{k_0}>q$ instad of $10^n>q$ you will get the desorden inequalities.

Comment: Oh, it is easy! Thanks Julián :)